# Formatting with floats

Tags: python, python-2.7

The code below isn't complete, but should give an idea of what I'm doing. What's irritating is that my table isn't lining up after '100.001'. I want to keep the same numbers, so is there something I can do to stop the '|' from sticking out after 100.001?

```
for j in numbers:
        print('{} {} {} {}\n'.format(number, "|", num, "|", etc, etc))     



 #output

      1       | 0.617  | 98.333  |  98.332  | 0.108 | 0.101   | 91.678  |

      2       | 0.617  | 98.332  |  98.332  | 0.101 | 0.101   | 100.001  |

      3       | 0.617  | 0.180   |  98.335  | 0.106 | 98.335  | 93.330  |

      4       | 0.617  | 0.107   |  98.336  | 0.105 | 0.101   | 95.004  |
```

Comment: what OS? you on unix?

Comment: I use a mac. Should that matter?

Comment: Well on unix I normally just pipe the output to `column -t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want format the output numbers. To do this you can use the formatting specifiers (similar to C the printf|sprintf|fprintf functions formatting specifiers).

Firstly, you should be specific about the format of the numbers, and then, all your output will be printed on that specific format. So if you want align '100.001', I suggest you to use the format DDD.ddd (three digits numbers with three decimals). In Python use the specifier ":06.3" like the following:

```
'{:06.3f}'.format(3.141592653589793)
```

Should print:

```
003.142
```

Take a look at the complete ref [here](https://pyformat.info/)

Comment: Thanks! That'll have to do. Ideally the two zeros before 3 would be invisible, but I don't suppose it matters.

Comment: @Anonypy: To omit the zeroes, just make it `'{:6.3f}'`; the `0` in the format string is what tells it to pad with zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

can you try `.ljust(10)` to get tabular structure.

```
value = 100.001
number = 3.3457
num = 10.2
etc = 34.1234
for i in range(10):
  print('{} | {} | {} | {}\n'.format(str(value).ljust(10), i, etc, etc))
```

Comment: Good. Except that in Python 2 we don't need to pass argument to `print` inside parenthesis.

Comment: Nope - gives the error: ValueError: cannot switch from automatic field numbering to manual field specification

Comment: I'm using {:.3f} atm

Comment: @Anonypy: Are you using floats or strings?